# Django: How do you access a model's instance from inside a manager?

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

```
class SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousManager(models.Manager):
    # Sorry, I'm sick of Foo and Spam for now.
    def get_query_set(self, account=None):
        return super(SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousManager,
                     self).get_query_set().filter(uncle=model_thats_using_this_manager_instance.uncle)
```

The magic I'm looking for is the "uncle=model_thats_using_this_manager_instance.uncle". It seems like I should be able to do this somehow. I know I could say `self.model` to get the model, but how to get the instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In methods like `object.related_name.create()` under the hood the Djangos sends a `hint` argument:

```
class UserQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self._hints)
        # >>> {'instance': <User: random-user>}
        print(self._hints.get('instance'))
        # >>> <User: random-user>
```

I'm using Django 1.11 nowadays.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't make sense to ask for an instance when you're using a manager. Managers are class-level attributes - if you try and do `foo.objects.all()` where `foo` is an instance of Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious, you will explicitly get an error:

```
AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious instances
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. You're example helped me to understand the context in which managers exist. I still need to find a way to better handle this situation application-wide vs having to write special code hither and thither.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you cannot access the model from inside a manager. It doesn't make sense as managers operate on the whole table.

You should do something like this in the model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    # some attributes here
    def getAllRelativesWithSameUncle(self):
        return Model.objects.filter(uncle = self.uncle)
```

or in the manager:

```
class SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousManager(models.Manager):
    def getSelfRelativesFor(self, model):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(uncle=model)
```

Comment: model method makes much more sense

Comment: I think you meant to say uncle=model_instance and (self, model_instance) rather than using the model itself as the filtering attribute.

Comment: Of course, thats why it is written in small letters ;) (I confess it could be misunderstood). Changed it....

Answer (score 0):

try `self.model`.

*From the Docs*

"Another thing to note is that Manager methods can access self.model to get the model class to which they’re attached." — https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods

What led to the answer: The manager knows what model to create when you call .create() from the manager.